# Any Other method instead of Dehydration store

Tags: soa, osb

Instead of dehydration store, can we use any other method that helps to prevent data loss in case of server failure in soa(bpel) process. Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can design a reliable messaging solution without using BPEL dehydration at all.

You just need to assess and ensure that you are not losing any other functional or non-functional benefits of dehydration.